# Stop infinite errors loop in browser's console

Tags: angular, google-chrome

There was a lot of questions about it, but I didn't find any suitable for me.

I'm using Angular 4 in my project, and there are situations where I get "cannot read of undefined" error. The problem is, that in a few seconds I get thousands of these errors and it makes my browser crash. Is there any way to stop printing these errors and prevent my browser to crash? I know there is a pause button, but can I define something like - when there more than 100 errors -> stop rendering?

Comment: please show us some code.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing any code, but when I've seen this issue, it's usually an issue with an infinite routing loop.

For example, you have a `/dashboard` page with a route guard on it that prevents access unless the user is authenticated. If the user isn't authenticated, the auth guard returns false and the user is redirected. In your routing config, on redirect, you're sending the user back to the `/dashboard` page, which restarts the process all over again. This will crash your browser.

Comment: Also, if you're doing some kind of error handling that redirects the user it can cause the same kind of issue.

Comment: It's not about any specific case. Usually I know where is the problem in my code.

Situation: I write some code with this error. Page reloads, error occurs, and after a few seconds browser crash so hard, that it's hard to close the tab, because of thousands of errors in console whick number is still increasing.

I'm looking for a solution that will stop it.